# Uncaught OAuthException matter

Tags: json, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

I'm building an application on Facebook, which gives me this error:

> "**Fatal error**: Uncaught OAuthBaseException: An active access token
>   must be used to query information about the current user. Thrown in
>   /membri/mercatinoalto/base_facebook.php on line 1254"

when clicking a button that brings up a file inside it calls the file 'facebook.php'.
This file recalls another file, 'base_facebook.php':

... 
require_once "base_facebook.php"; 
...

In 'base_facebook.php', at line 1254 I find this function:

> protected function throwAPIException ($ result) {
>
> $ e = new FacebookApiException ($ result);
>
> switch ($ e-> getType ()) {
>          // OAuth 2.0 draft 00 style
>
> case 'OAuthException':
>
> // OAuth 2.0 draft 10 style
>
> case 'invalid_token':
>
> // REST server errors are just Exceptions
>
> case 'Exception':
>
> $ message = $ e-> getMessage ();
>
> if ((strpos ($ message, 'Error validating access token')! == false) ||
>
> (strpos ($ message, 'Invalid OAuth access token')! == false) ||
>
> (strpos ($ message, 'An active access token must be used')! == false)
>
> ) {
>              $ this> destroySession (); 
>            }
>
> break; 
>        }

I can't find wher I'm going wrong. 
Can you help me, please?

Comment: I upgraded the SDK version, but still the error points to the code:  $ e = new FacebookApiException ($ result);

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a valid Access Token to be able to request user data.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/